# Get compile-time variable at runtime

Tags: actionscript-3, namespaces, compile-time-constant

I am trying to use the "define" mxmlc compiler option to embed compile-time constants into my SWF files.

```
<mxmlc ...>
    <define name="NAMES::PluginCompileTime" value="Hello World!"/>
</mxmlc>
```

I can access this variable if I "hardcode" it into my codebase, as so:

```
public static const PLUGIN_COMPILED_TIME:String = NAMES::PluginCompileTime;
```

However, I would like to be able to do this at runtime using something like getDefinitionByName():

```
var value:* = flash.utils.getDefinitionByName("NAMES::PluginCompileTime");
```

This throws the following error:

```
ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable PluginCompileTime is not defined.
```

Does anyone know of a way to accomplish loading a compile-time constant in a namespace at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile-time constants aren't available at runtime.  They're only available at compile-time.

If you need its value as a namespace const, then the correct solution is to "hardcode" it as you've done.

Comment: Thanks :) I guess I just kind of hoped that it would be possible to look it up as if it were a definition in the SWF file.

Comment: @tkk: I'm wondering why you need to do this.  If you ever need the value at any point in your code, you can just write `var something:String = NAMES::PluginCompileTime;`.  I can't see why you'd need an explicit copy of the value in a namespace global.

Comment: Well, one reason would be that having to hardcode the value in there introduces a compile time dependency to the codebase. If I don't have to hardcode, default values can be used instead, making my compile a little more "variable." :)